# Diposing a child process created with fork() in C

Tags: c, linux, process, fork

My C homework program multiplies two matrices. Each entry of the product matrix is calculated by a child process created with `fork()`. The child calculates this and sends the data to the parent using a pipe. So if the product matrix has a size 10x10, I will create 100 child processes. Works fine.

Then I noticed that for very large matrices, this was not working. After doing some inspection, I realized that it's because it won't create any more child processes after a certain number (the `pid` returns negative). Like, some sort of limit, which makes sense.

Indeed, I can't expect my computer to allow a program to spawn several thousands of child processes, so obviously my program can't multiply super large matrices. Alright.

Then it occurred to me: well, I don't need ***all*** the child processes immediately. I could make 100, let them do their thing, and then create the next 100, and so on until all the necessary calculations are done for my matrix product.

My program is essentially a loop that iterates `rows * columns` times. Each iteration, it makes a child process. So I decided that, for every 100 iterations, I would put a `sleep()` thing. My hope was that when the `sleep()` thing was done, the 100 previous child processes would die out, "freeing" all the space necessary for the next 100 batch. Alas, it did not make a difference: program behaves exactly the same (except that it is slower, of course).

So, given that the `sleep()` thing did not work, my suspicion is that I am not properly "killing" the child processes. This is how a child process dies:

```
// Close the pipe!
close(fd[0]);
close(fd[1]);
// Exit
exit(0);
```

And the parent, after reading the data, also closes the pipe:

```
read(fd[0], buffer, sizeof(buffer));
close(fd[0]);
close(fd[1]);
```

---

So my question is: since I am unable to make new child processes because I have already created too many, it seems like I am not properly disposing of the old processes. How can I dispose them correctly?

Comment: Look at `wait` which lets you know conclusively that a given child process is complete.

Comment: But don't you know the child is done upon reading from the pipe?

Comment: @ChiefTwoPencils yeah right? So the `sleep()` (or nothing at all) should be fine! I think.

Comment: Forking hundreds of processes is slow.  Much better to use threads.  Then you won't have to deal with pipes and child processes.

Comment: There's no guarantee of that. `sleep(1)` is a bad controller. It's far better to use the pipe itself as an indicator, since it's a blocking call, maybe signals. You could use `wait` as well. You could `while(1)` waiting for `SIGCHLD`, read the pipe, call wait, `kill` the child if necessary.

Comment: Either way, you shouldn't guess. Keep track of them, if one exits spawn another, I wouldn't wait for them all to finish.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What [`sleep(3)`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/sleep) does is putting the process to temporarily sleep, but still it keeps it alive.

As you stated, you need to make sure the children-process are dead before creating more. To do that, children need to [`exit(2)`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/exit) properly when they finish their job, and parent process should use [`wait(2)`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/wait) on them in order to [reap](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zombie_process) them, and make space in the process table.

A possible solution is to [`fork(2)`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/fork) some children processes to do some part of the job, then [`wait(2)`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/wait) them to finish before `fork`ing more of them to do some other part of the job.

Comment: Indeed `wait` or `waitpid` is the way to clean up after children to make space for more.  +1